# onMouseOver/onMouseOut fires on Child elements

Tags: jquery, onmouseover, jquery-hover, onmouseout

This is my basic code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function play(id){
    $("#player"+id).jPlayer("play", 0);
    $("#jp-play"+id).css("background-color", "#999999");
    $("#jp-pause"+id).css("background-color", "#999999");
    $("#jp-play"+id).css("background-image", "url(images/voice_over/hover.png)");
    $("#jp-pause"+id).css("background-image", "url(images/voice_over/hover.png)");
}

function end(id){
    $("#player"+id).jPlayer("stop");
    $("#jp-play"+id).css("background-color", "#656565");
    $("#jp-pause"+id).css("background-color", "#656565");
    $("#jp-play"+id).css("background-image", "url(images/voice_over/normal.png)");
    $("#jp-pause"+id).css("background-image", "url(images/voice_over/normal.png)");
}
</script>


<div class="jp-audio" onMouseOver="play(\''.$id.'\');" onMouseOut="end(\''.$id.'\');">
    //child elements, id from PHP
</div>
```

This plays audio when the div is hovered over.
There are several divs (that each play different audio).

But hovering over child elements in each div (like text) will stop the audio.

I understand that this is something to do with bubbling/propagation.
I am using jQuery and simply tried adding event.stopPropagtion(); to the functions but it didn't work.

Other solutions require using .hover() etc.
But then how would I get the id of which file to play?

I hope that makes sense.
I'm finding it hard to explain what I mean.

Any help would be appreciated.

Now my working code is:

```
var play = function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('file-id');
    $("#player"+id).jPlayer("play", 0);
    $("#jp-play"+id).css("background-color", "#999999");
    $("#jp-pause"+id).css("background-color", "#999999");
    $("#jp-play"+id).css("background-image", "url(images/voice_over/hover.png)");
    $("#jp-pause"+id).css("background-image", "url(images/voice_over/hover.png)");
}

var end = function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('file-id');
    $("#player"+id).jPlayer("stop");
    $("#jp-play"+id).css("background-color", "#656565");
    $("#jp-pause"+id).css("background-color", "#656565");
    $("#jp-play"+id).css("background-image", "url(images/voice_over/normal.png)");
    $("#jp-pause"+id).css("background-image", "url(images/voice_over/normal.png)");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.jp-audio').hover(play, end);        
});

<div class="jp-audio" file-id="'.$id.'">stuff</div>
```

It's important to have the variables before the .hover, especially when the content is dynamically loaded based on user input.
I had it around the other way and when using innerHTML it would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do it is set $id to be a attr of the html element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.js-audio').hover(play, end);        
});

var play = function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('file-id');
   ....
}

<div class="js-audio" file-id="$id"></div>
```

Comment: Indeed, I wrote basic example to demonstrate that `.hover` effect: http://jsfiddle.net/jG6uP/

Comment: I can't get this to work. The file-id attribute is working fine,
but nothing happens when I hover over the divs,
I've added the new code to my question

Comment: I figured it out, you needed to use $(document).ready, which I thought I had already tried, but I tried it again and it works now

Comment: The variables need to be declared BEFORE the .hover if you are using dynamically created elements (via JS).
As the .ready will fire before they are created otherwise (but you want it to fire after)